# python read() function read more characters than specified

Tags: python, readfile

first_file.txt

```
“
Hello World
This is our new text file
and this is another line.
Why? Because we can.
“
```

The result is wired to me,see below.

```
with open('first_file.txt') as f:
    print(f.read(2))
    print(f.read(3))
    print(f.read(8))
    print(f.read(15))
    print(f.read())
```

Can anyone explain read(8) and read(15)? See below for the output.

```
He
llo
 World
T
his is our new 
text file
and this is another line.
Why? Because we can.
```

Comment: What's unclear to you?

Comment: Try `print(repr(f.read(n)))`, e.g. `print(repr(f.read(8)))`. That should make it clearer.

Comment: `read(8)` returns the space after `Hello`, the world `World`, the trailing newline, and the `T` from the next line.  Were you expecting it to stop at the end of the current line?

Comment: @ReputationFarmer can understand why this is the result, read(2) and read(3) printed `He` and `llo`, I could understand, but when it comes to read(8) and read(15), I just got confused.

Comment: @JohnGordon but how about read(15), it printed `text file
and this is another line.` even more than 15 characters.

Comment: No, it printed `his is our new `, which is 15 characters.

Answer (score 3):

The output seems weird because it is printing the new lines too. If you count the number of characters it prints, the output is correct when considering the newline characters.

When you call `print()`, python will add a newline to the output. Below is what python is seeing every time you call print:

```
>>> f.read(2):  'He'+\n              <- 2 characters + newline
>>> f.read(3):  'llo'+\n             <- 3 characters + newline
>>> f.read(8):  ' World\nT'+\n       <- 8 characters + newline
>>> f.read(15): 'his is our new '+\n <- 15 characters + newline
>>> 
>>> f.read():   'text file\nand this is another line.\nWhy? Because we can.'+\n
```

When you call read on a file, it moves the cursor position by the specified number of characters. When you call read again, it will pick back up where it left off. When you don't specify a number, it will read until the end of the file.

Comment: When print read(2) and read(3), I got what I understand`"He"` and `"llo"`, but when I try to get read(8) it shows me  

  `World
  T`      

and read(15), I got
`his is our new 
  text file`

which is even more than 15 characters.

Comment: I have updated my answer with more information. This basically comes down to the fact that there are whitespace characters that I think you are forgetting to account for.